# Localization in commutative ring with unity: condition on localizing set

Tags: ring-theory, localization

Let $A$ be a commutative ring with unity $1$ different from $0$ and $S\subset A$ be a multiplicatively closed. (**Edited** after Answer/comment by Bernard: $S$ is multiplicatively closed means whenever $x,y\in S$ then $xy\in S$; and we take $S\neq \phi$.)

On set $\{\frac{a}{s}:a\in A, s\in S\}$ we define equivalence relation 
$\frac{a}{s}\sim \frac{a'}{s'}$ iff $(as'-a's)t=0$ for some $t\in S.$
On the set $A_S$ of equivalence classes, we define usual additions and multiplications as in $\mathbb{Q}$ we do.

My questions are simply whether following statements are correct?

**1.** $A$ will be ring with unity different from $0$ only if $1\in S$.

**2.** Suppose $1\notin S$. Let $S^*=\{1\}\cup S$. Then $A_S$ and $A_{S^*}$ are isomorphic rings (i.e. there is bijection $f:A_S\rightarrow A_{S^*}$ which is additive homoorphism and preserves multiplication).

---

My exact doubts:

(a) I didn't find any reason to include/exclude $1$ in defining localization, which forced me for true/false testing statement **1**

(b) In the case when $A$ is integral domain, the answer of Q.2 is Yes (it is an exercise in Janusz's Algebraic number theory.) But my question is - if $A$ 
not integral domain but just commutative ring with unity different from $0$, is statement **2** correct?

Comment: What does question mean, exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For question 2, $A_S$ and $A_{S^*}$ are solutions of the same universal problem (making the elements of $S$ and the elements of $S\cup\{1\}$ invertible are equivalent problems), so they're isomorphic.

On the other hand, it depends on what is your definition of a multiplicatively closed set. With *Bourbaki*'s definition:

> A subset $S$ of $A$ is called multiplicative if every finite
>   product of elements of $S$ belongs to $S$.
>
> This is the same as saying that $1 \in S$ and that the product of two elements of $S$ belong to $S$.

your question is meaningless.

Comment: Dear, could you explain *making the elements of $S$ and the elements of $S\cup \{ 1\}$ are equivalent problems*? My definition of multiplicatively closed set is as follows: *$S$ is mult. closed if $x,y\in S$ implies $xy\in S$. (This may cause problem whether empty set is multiplicatively closed! So, we could assume, $S\neq \phi$.)

Comment: Sorry for mistyping. I meant making these elements invertible, of course. I hope it makes the explanation clearer. I think the correct  definition is Bourbaki's – all the more so as the simplest way to ensure $S\ne\varnothing$ is to suppose $S\ni1$.

Comment: Bernard: Can you tell me the exact reference of Bourbaki where multiplicative set  $S$ is defined as you mentioned in answer?

Comment: Here you are: N. Bourbaki, *Commutative Algebra*, ch. IIn *Localisation*, §2, Rings ans Modules of Fractions, Definition 1.